# Android IntentService Queue

Tags: android

Suppose i have two classes that inherit from IntentService. Now quoting from the documentation

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

Now suppose my classes are called `SericeA extends IntentService`, and `ServiceB extends IntentService`now when i call startService for an object of type ServiceA and startService for an Object of type ServiceB, will these both be handled by the same worker thread. Is there a System wide worker thread, or just a worker thread associated with a particular IntentService.

Kind Reagrds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will these both be handled by the same worker thread

No.

> or just a worker thread associated with a particular IntentService.

Yes.

You can tell this by looking at [the source code to `IntentService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) and noticing that each `IntentService` creates its own `HandlerThread`.